# Which convex functions have $D_u f(x) = f(u)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

When calculating the directional derivatives of the convex function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\infty, & \text{if } x \ne 0, \\
0, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
I found that $$D_u f(0) = f(u), \tag{$\star$} \label{eq:1}$$ where the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $u$ is
$$
D_u f(x)
= \inf_{h > 0} \frac{f(x + h u) - f(x)}{h}.
$$
The same seems to be true for $f(x) = \begin{cases} \infty, & \text{if } x > 0, \\ 0, & \text{if } x \le 0 \end{cases}$.

> I was wondering if one can neatly characterise all proper convex functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to (- \infty, \infty]$ such that \eqref{eq:1} holds (is it just certain indicator functions)?

Note that the non-convex sign function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & x > 0, \\
0, & x = 0, \\
- 1, & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
also fulfils \eqref{eq:1}.

Comment: First of all by letting $u = 0$ and using $(\star)$ you get $f(0) = 0$. Now let $u > 0$, using the definition of $D_u$ you can easily prove that $D_u f(0) = u D_1 f(0)$, similarly if $u < 0$ then $D_u f(0) = u D_{-1} f(0)$. Now by using $(\star)$ you can find how $f$ behaves

Comment: @Ramanujan No, you get $f(u) = uf(1) \; , \; f(-u) = -uf(-1)$ for all $u > 0$.

Comment: @Paul Plugging in your second formula $u = 1$ we get $f(-1) = - f(-1)$, implying $f(-1) = 0$, but the first function I mentioned does not have this property.

Comment: @Paul Maybe the property you mention only holds for all $u \in \text{dom}(f) := \{ v \in \mathbb R: f(v) \in \mathbb R \}$?